# What is the probability that in a random sample of $10$ fuses, exactly 3 will fail building standards?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose that $30$ percent of certain electrical fuses fail to meet building standards. What is the probability that in a random sample of $10$ such fuses, exactly 3 will fail building standards?

I was told to use the Binomial experiment but I do not see that nowhere in my notes. If anybody can assist me with that formula and the meaning of the terms, I would appreciate it

Comment: Nice question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.statisticshowto.com/binomial-distribution-formula/

So the answer would be:

$$P(\text {Exactly 3 failures})=[^{10}C_3]\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^7\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)^3$$

To verify, check here: http://math.illinoisstate.edu/krzysio/1-13-7-KO-Exercise.pdf

Comment: wow my professor gave me a question from the 80s lol

Comment: You have about 20 outstanding Questions, most of them with at least one excellent answer. Among all your Questions, you have Accepted only two Answers. What is keeping you from Accepting helpful answers? That's the way we know a question has a satisfactory answer and needs no further attention.

Comment: @BruceET You might want to make this comment on the question's comment box.